# IE7 Bug With Nested UL's and CSS Filter

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm not sure that this will be easy to explain without just showing you so here is an example -

http://jsfiddle.net/46gL8/1/

When viewed in FF, Chrome, and IE8/9 the example works as expected. When viewed in IE7 the nested `UL` is rendered inside of the parent despite both being positioned absolutely. Things like `z-index` make no difference and the only fix was to remove the `filter:` line from the shadow class.

I suppose it would be fine to just render a regular border or something in IE7 but it would be awesome if anyone had any insight!

Comment: Really, you're best bet is going to be to drop the filter and only have modern browsers display with a drop-shadow. Will save you a lot of headaches down the road. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Yeah I'm perfectly fine with just dropping support for the drop shadow in IE7, just curious to see if anyone knows anything about these nebulous filters. As for the answer to that question, most SO users would agree with that sentiment, but most marketing dept's would disagree ;)

Comment: What @Moses said, this is progressive enhancement and graceful degredation.

Comment: Agreed. I opened a bounty just to see if anyone could shed some light on this issue not because I couldnt resolve it with workarounds. Ill probably just remove the question if it goes unanswered. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Removing the `position:absolute;` from the first menu solves the problem, but probably not what you want. Other solution is to look at this menu, which supports shadows: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the filter cuts off all content that falls outside the filtered box. If you remove the submenu from the hierarchy of the main menu, it does work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wyDTQ/

Of course, I don't know how you're constructing your menu, so that might not be what you want. It does fix your issue, though.

Comment: This is what I already ended up doing for the production release and it works fine. I opened the bounty to see if anyone could shed some light on the bug itself.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I cannot shed any light on the specific internal workings of IE7's filters, presumably IE7 can only render filters around boxes, and not boxes upon boxes, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Seem you only need an explanation rather then a solution. Everything you need to know about the filter property is explained by Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx, no further details is given to why or how it works in certain scenarios.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but that doesn't really help either. I will be closing this question.